# Why is my react native firebase login not working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have an extra screen where I can login with email and password and by clicking on sign in.
Then in theory it should take me outside that login screen because I have that auth listener in my app.js. But when I login nothing happens it stays in the Login Screen

Inside my login.js

```
  const handleSignIn = () => {
    auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password)
      .then(console.log("xeah"));
  };
```

Inside my app.js

```
  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Login />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
      <Button title="bye" onPress={auth().signOut()}></Button>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are executing the signOut() method once APP got the state for the authorization.
Try to change the auth().signOut() to auth().signOut as below

```
 return (
  <View>
    <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
    <Button title="bye" onPress={auth().signOut}></Button>
  </View>
 );
```